# macOS: How to open the "Open with" menue from code?

Tags: macos, finder

on macOS in Finder there is the option "Open with >" in the context menu of files, which shows a menu with all available apps being able to open the file. So the user can choose, with which app the file must be opened.

I would like to open this menu from code for a specific file.
In Windows it goes like this

```
Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "shell32.dll, OpenAs_RunDLL " + file);
```

but I can't figure out, how this goes in macOS.

Comment: Are you asking how to display the menu in an app that you're writing, or are you hoping to programmatically activate the Open With... menu in an existing app that you didn't write? That is, are you building a user interface or trying to manipulate the UI of an existing app?

Comment: "Are you asking how to display the menu in an app that you're writing / are you building a user interface" - Yes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adjust this following AppleScript code to suit your needs.

If you have a file selected in Finder, and you run this following code in Script Editor.app, it will open a dialog for you to choose a new application to open your selected Finder file with, then will open that file with your chosen app.

```
activate
set chosenApp to (choose application with prompt ¬
    "Choose  Your Preferred Default Application" as alias)

tell application "Finder"
    set thisFile to selection -- The Selected File In Front Finder Window
    set appID to id of chosenApp
    try
        open thisFile as text using application file id appID
    on error errMsg number errNum
        display dialog "Please Go Back And Select A File In Finder To Be Opened." & linefeed & ¬
            "Then Come Back And Run This Code Again" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK"
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, will try to find out, how to call `open thisFile as text using application file id appID`  from code

Answer (score -2):

Steps:

1. Start the terminal by pressing command-space --> type in: terminal
2. when the terminal is running you switch to the applications folder:
   'cd Applications'
3. You can run the apps like this: open -a GIMP-2.10.app

more info:
https://osxdaily.com/2007/02/01/how-to-launch-gui-applications-from-the-terminal/

Comment: The OP would like to display an "Open with..." menu from his code, not from the terminal.

Comment: My bad, I overlooked the running from code part and thought the intention was to start the app from the command line (as "code"  not via the GUI). Won't happen again.